# AWS Add user to Cognito group when registering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to make it so when I register I get add to the Traveler group in AWS Cognito.
I have tried to add it with mutliple ways but it did not help me.

I have tried a lambda function that triggers on preSignUp with the following code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-north-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_DOMITS_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
    const GRAPHQL_API_KEY = process.env.API_DOMITS_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT;
    const USER_POOL_ID = process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID;
    const GROUP_NAME = "Traveler";

    // Check if userAttributes is present in event.request
    const userEmail = event.request?.userAttributes?.email;

    if (!userEmail) {
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                errors: [{ message: 'User email or password not provided or invalid.' }],
            }),
        };
    }

    // GraphQL mutation to create user
    const createUserQuery = /* GraphQL */ `
        mutation CREATE_USER($input: CreateUserInput!) {
            createUser(input: $input) {
                email,
            }
        }
    `;

    // GraphQL variables for creating user
    const createUserVariables = {
        input: {
            email: userEmail,
        },
    };

    // Options for the GraphQL request to create user
    const createUserOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "x-api-key": GRAPHQL_API_KEY,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: createUserQuery,
            variables: createUserVariables,
        }),
    };

    // Response object
    const response = {};

    try {
        const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
        const params = {
            GroupName: GROUP_NAME,
            UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
            Username: userEmail,
        };
        await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup(params).promise();
        // If successful, return a success response
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'User created and added to group successfully.' }),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding user to group:', error);
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                errors: [
                    {
                        message: error.message,
                        stack: error.stack,
                    },
                ],
            }),
        };
    }

    // This return statement should be placed inside the try block or after the successful execution of the GraphQL mutation
    // return {
    //     ...response,
    //     body: JSON.stringify(response.body),
    // };
};
```

I also tried to make it in my ConfirmRegister (this is where I enter the confirmation code to confirm my account.) My lambda function has the permissions: AdministratorAccess and the AmazonCognitoPowerUser

```
import React, { FormEvent, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import DigitInputs from '../ui/DigitsInputs/DigitsInputs';
import './ConfirmRegister.css';

import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

function ConfirmEmail() {
    const [isConfirmed, setIsConfirmed] = useState(false);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const inputRef = useRef([]);

    const userEmail = location.state === null ? "" : location.state.email;

    async function onSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let code = "";
        inputRef.current.forEach((input: HTMLInputElement) => {
            code += input.value;
        });

        try {
            const result = await Auth.confirmSignUp(userEmail, code);
            if (result === 'SUCCESS') {
                setIsConfirmed(true);
                // Check if the user is authenticated before adding them to the group
                const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
                // Add the user to the group 'Travelor'
                await addUserToGroup(user.attributes.email, "Travelor");
                setTimeout(() => navigate('/'), 3000);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setErrorMessage('Invalid verification code, please check your email!');
            console.error('Error confirming sign up:', error);
        }
    }

    const handleResendCode = () => {
        if (userEmail === '') {
            navigate('/register');
        } else {
            Auth.resendSignUp(userEmail);
        }
    };

    const form = (
        <div className="confirmEmailContainer">
            <div className="confirmEmailTitle">Verify your registration</div>
            <form className="confirmEmailForm" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className="enter6DigitText">Enter 6 digit code sent to your email</div>
                <DigitInputs amount={6} inputRef={inputRef} className="confirmEmailDigitsInput" />
                {errorMessage && <div className="errorText">{errorMessage}</div>}
                <button className="verifyRegisterButton" type="submit">Verify registration</button>
                <div className="notReceivedCodeText">
                    Not received a code? Check your spam folder or let us resend a code.
                </div>
                <button className="resendCodeButton" onClick={handleResendCode}>Resend code</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

    const confirmedPopup = (
        <div className="confirmemail-container">
            <p className="confirmemail-card_title">Success!</p>
            <p className="confirmemail-card_text">Your email is now verified! You will be redirected shortly</p>
        </div>
    );

    return isConfirmed ? confirmedPopup : form;
}

async function addUserToGroup(userEmail, groupName) {
    try {
        // Get current authenticated user credentials
        const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
        const idToken = currentSession.getIdToken();

        // Configure AWS
        const credentials = {
            accessKeyId: idToken.payload['cognito:accessKeyId'],
            secretAccessKey: idToken.payload['cognito:secretKey'],
            sessionToken: idToken.getJwtToken()
        };

        // Get AWS region from Amplify configuration
        const region = Auth.configure().region;

        // Configure AWS SDK with obtained credentials
        AWS.config.update({
            region: region,
            credentials: credentials
        });

        // Create AWS Cognito IdentityServiceProvider object
        const cognitoISP = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

        // Get AWS user pool ID from Amplify configuration
        const userPoolId = Auth.configure().userPoolId;

        // Add user to group
        const groupParams = {
            GroupName: groupName,
            UserPoolId: userPoolId,
            Username: userEmail
        };

        await cognitoISP.adminAddUserToGroup(groupParams).promise();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding user to group:', error);
        throw new Error(`Error adding user to group: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

export default ConfirmEmail;
```

Comment: Which errors are you seeing?